# NVMe wd sn570 not recognized

Tags: macos, ssd

I have an NVMe hard disk be cause I need to replace my MacBook Pro 11,1 original hard drive. I have used an external box to initialize the hard disk using macOS disk utility, at the moment when I try to reinstall OS X it will not be recognized. The hd is a WD sn570 from 500gb, is there any solution I can try?My actual system is installed macOS big sur

Comment: *"initialize the hard disk using macOS disk utility"* Exactly how did you initialise it? You need to be in Device View [Cmd/2] then Erase using GUID/APFS Disks are usually shipped as MBR/ExFAT, which would prevent the Mac from formatting as APFS - it would not be offered as an option until you switch to GUID.. If you can get to terminal, please copy/paste the results of `diskutil list` so we can check the formatting.

Comment: I’ve selected from disk utility of big sur the apfs filesystem, there is no GUID Option, so if I understand well, I need to use diskutil from terminal?

Comment: To try solve the problem I’m now cloning the entire disk using carbon copy cloner, but not sure if this will work

Comment: You can only select APFS if the drive is already using GUID. Yes, you need terminal for `diskutil`. I've never tested CCC with newer 'dual volume' macOS, idk if it still works as well as it used to. There's a blog about it - https://bombich.com/blog/2020/11/03/yes-you-can-have-bootable-backups-on-macos-big-sur

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. I will test the cloned drive and Let you know if worked as expected

Comment: Probably I was only initializing the drive and not in the correct way from disk utility